# Is this solution to Hartshorne Exercise III.10.2 correct?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Exercise III.10.2 in Hartshone's *Algebraic Geometry* is [discussed in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830565/hartshorne-ex-iii-10-2-on-smooth-morphisms). The accepted answer proceeds by showing that the smooth locus is open on $X$, then transferring this to $Y$ using the fact that the morphism in question is closed.

As a commenter notes, it seems very strange that the full strength of properness hypothesis is not used. We are only using the fact that proper morphisms are closed, and not, for example, that they are universally closed or of finite type. Further, we are only supposing $X$ is locally Noetherian, a weaker hypothesis than being a variety (which the problem stipulates). However, I'm not able to find an error. Is this proof correct? Can we really get away with much weaker hypotheses, as the answer suggests?

(This question has been edited for clarity.)

Comment: The answer you cite proves that the smooth locus in the domain $X$ is an open subset.  The complement is a closed subset.  The image of that closed set in the target $Y$ is a closed subset of $Y$ since the morphism is closed.  By hypothesis, the open complement contains the point $y$ of $Y$.  Thus this open complement is a neighborhood of $y$ in $Y$ over which the morphism is smooth.

Comment: Yes. As Jason states here, and as I remark in my answer it is enough to take the morphism to be closed. I don't really see what the problem could be as the argument is quite simple? Anyhow, I've looked up the relevant reference. It is EGA IV-4 12.1.1. The theorem there is also stated only for proper morphisms, but in the proof it is mentioned that it is enough to consider closed maps

Comment: Just to clarify. We also need to assume that the morphism is flat and of finite presentation. Once we have this, smoothness is equivalent to the freeness of the sheaf of relative differentials

Comment: @Rieux Hi! Thanks for your comments and the reference -- you have put my mind at ease. If you copy them into an answer, I would be happy to accept it.